# how to increment a counter written into a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I am making a count of how many times a module fails into a file. so whenever it fails, i open the file, increment the number in the file and close it. How i can i do it with opening the file just once instead of opening it twice once for reading and another of writing.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumes a file named counter.txt in the same dir as the script is invoked from. The file should have nothing other than the number in it.

```
File.open 'counter.txt' , 'r+' do |file|
  num = file.gets.to_i
  file.rewind
  file.puts num.next
end
```

Basically, it [opens the file](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002239) 'counter.txt' for [reading and writing starting at the beginning of the file](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html) It uses the block form of open in order to ensure the file is closed when it is done. It [gets the number](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002272) and then [converts it to an integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000787) to get the current count. It [rewinds the file pointer](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002281) so that it is at the beginning of the file again (because we want to write over the old number) Then [prints out to the file](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002252) the incremented number.

Comment: for the first time. if i want to create a file and write 0 in it. it is throwing an exception as we are opening with r+ mode. how to handle this situation?

Comment: Is there a way to do this with locking the file, so it'll work if multiple processes are running the script?